# Insert contents into innerHTML without clearing what's already inside

Tags: javascript, ajax, innerhtml

I'm trying to create a post button that inserts the latest posts into a div, without clearing everything that is inside. My current code inserts the new divider, but clears everything inside it, so i end up with just the last post.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

The code is:

```
var xmlHttp

function submitNews() {
  xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();

  if (xmlHttp==null) {
    alert ("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    return;
  }

  var content = document.getElementById('newsfeed_box').value;
  var uid = document.getElementById('pu_uid').innerHTML;

  var url="ajax/submit_post.php";
  url=url+"?post="+content+"&id="+uid;
  url=url+"&validate="+Math.random();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChange;

  xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChange() {
  switch(xmlHttp.readyState) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('successs').innerHTML = "<img src=\"style/images/loader.gif\" />";
      document.getElementById('successs').style.display = "block";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById('successs').innerHTML = "<img src=\"style/images/loader.gif\" />";
      document.getElementById('successs').style.display = "block";
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById('successs').innerHTML = "<img src=\"style/images/loader.gif\" />";
      document.getElementById('successs').style.display = "block";
      break;
    case 4:
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById('successs').appendChild(newdiv);
      break;
  }
}

// creating the XMLHttpRequest
function GetXmlHttpObject() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: You realize the code you have that "inserts the new divider" is only 1 of 4 `switch` cases? And it's these 3 *other* cases that actually clears the div?

Comment: Unless you're specifically trying to avoid it, I would recommend using a framework like jQuery to help out with some of this ajax voodoo.  In the long run, it will make your life significantly easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your switch statement.  Your cases to handle 1 - 3 completely reset the innerHTML of your element.  You may not be able to see it, but these cases are getting hit.  Try moving your loading image into a different container and it will start to work.

```
  switch(xmlHttp.readyState) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src=\"style/images/loader.gif\" />";
      document.getElementById('status').style.display = "block";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src=\"style/images/loader.gif\" />";
      document.getElementById('status').style.display = "block";
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src=\"style/images/loader.gif\" />";
      document.getElementById('status').style.display = "block";
      break;
    case 4:
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById('successs').appendChild(newdiv);
      break;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. copy the inner html into a variable
2. mix the new content and the variable the way you need (new + old OR old + new)
3. set the inner html = your mixed stuff

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
whatever.innerHTML += additionalInfo;
```

Comment: I've tried that. It still clears whatever is inside, then adds the new contents.

Comment: I just tested this out in IE6,7,8, FF3, Chrome3 and it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

```
var currentContent = document.getElementById('status').innerHTML;

document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = currentContent+"new stuff";
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer. Just code answers might be deleted.